When one can use KKT
I wanted to compare the following two optimization problems and why we use KKT for one of them and don't use KKT for the other.
Problem A
Solve
$$
\max f(x, y, z) \text { with } f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2+z^2
$$
subject to
$$
x-y=1 \text { and } y^2-z^2=1 .
$$
The Solution provided is as follows,
Notice that $f$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In other words, as $\|(x, y, z)\| \rightarrow+\infty$, we have that $f \rightarrow+\infty$. Since the set of points $\left\{(x, y, z): x-y=1\right.$ and $\left.y^2-z^2=1\right\}$ is unbounded, $\max f$ subject to $x-y=1$ and $y^2-z^2=1$ is plus infinity.
If I however solve it with KKT I get $(0, -1, 0)$, $(2,1,0)$
Why am I not able to conclude that these points are the optimizers? I thought it may have something to do with the boundedness of the region but I saw the solution to another problem that is unbounded but they are able to use KKT
Problem B
Solve
$$
\max f(x, y) \text { with } f(x, y)=-x^2+4 x-y^2+6 y
$$
subject to
$$
x+y \leq 3 \text { and }-2 x+y \leq 2 .
$$
The Solution provided is as follows
Our Lagrangian is
$$
L\left(x, y, \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3\right)=-x^2+4 x-y^2+6 y-\lambda_1(x+y-3)-\lambda_2(y-2 x-2) .
$$
Our KT conditions are
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_x L=-2 x+4-\lambda_1+2 \lambda_2 & =0 \\
\partial_y L=-2 y+6-\lambda_1-\lambda_2 & =0 \\
\lambda_1(x+y-3) & =0 \\
\lambda_2(y-2 x-2) & =0 \\
\lambda_1, \lambda_2 & \geq 0 .
\end{aligned}
$$
When $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$, we have the point $(2,3)$. But this point is inadmissible; it doesn't live in the constrained region.
When $\lambda_1=0$, but $\lambda_2 \neq 0$, we find $\lambda_2<0$, which contradicts the complementary slackness conditions. So there are no points to consider from this case.
When $\lambda_2=0$, but $\lambda_1 \neq 0$, we find the point $(1,2)$. In this case, $\lambda_1=2$.
When $\lambda_1 \neq 0$ and $\lambda_2 \neq 0$, we find $\lambda_2<0$, which contradicts the complementary slackness conditions. So there are no points to consider from this case.
Since $\nabla g_1=(1,1)$ and $\nabla g_2=(-2,1)$ are linearly independent, the CQ always holds. And there are no points to add.
Thus, the only point to consider is $(1,2)$ with $\lambda^*=(2,0)$. Note that $L(x, y, 2,0)$ is concave. So $(1,2)$ is indeed the maximizer, and the maximum value of $f$ over our region is 11 .
